# Google Apps Script での実行環境判定

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Apps Script の V8 エンジンを動かしてみています。

疑問がわきました。
GASのエンジンはV8か、Rhino かがあると思いますが、この２つはどのように判定するのがよいでしょうか？

また、あるコードが、普通の node で動いているのか、Google Apps Script で動いているのか、を判定するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

また、さらには、Google Apps Script でも、Google SpreadSheet からの呼び出しか、そうではないのか、という判定方法も知りたいです。

いくつかの質問になってしまっていますが、つまりは、実行環境を判定する方法はGASの場合どうするのでしょうか？ということになります。

ブラウザかNodeか、あるいは、どんなブラウザなのか、を判定する方法はネットでよく見かけたのですが、GASの場合はそのようなコードを見かけませんでした。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ご希望の方法かどうかわかりませんが、Manifestファイルを見るのはいかがでしょうか。V8が有効になっているとruntimeVersionの値は"V8"になります。新規でGoogle Apps Scriptのプロジェクトを作成した際は、今のところ、runtimeVersionのプロパティは表示されません。一方、一度V8を有効にし、その後、無効にするとruntimeVersionの値は"DEPRECATED_ES5"として表示されます。Manifestファイル自体はApps Script APIを使うことでスクリプトでもチェックすることが可能です。[参考1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/), [参考2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent) シンプルな方法としては、ES5では使えないメソッドを使ってエラーが発生するかどうかを確認するなどもありかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございました。ずいぶん遅くなったのですが検証してみましたが、私はあまりGasに慣れておらず、manifestファイルを読み込む方法はリンクを頂いた、参考1,参考2,で示されたページをみてもわかりませんでした。

代替案でうまくいきましたので別回答で記載しておきます。

Answer (score 0):

調べました所、公式ページからの情報でなんとかなりました。

詳細な情報は下記の2つの所に記載があります。

V8 Runtime Overview  |  Apps Script  |  Google Developers
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime

Migrating scripts to the V8 runtime  |  Apps Script  |  Google Developers
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration

たいていのコードは一方がエラーで、他方がエラーではない、というものでそちらで判定するのもよさそうなのですが、判定処理に例外を混ぜたくなかったので(おそらく低速ですから)、例外以外の差異はないかな、とみてたところ

Object.prototype.toSource の有無みたいな事が書かれていました。

実際に動かしてみたところ

```
  console.log(typeof Object.toSource === 'undefined')
```

これが、Rhinoの場合は、false 、V8の場合は、true になるのがわかりましたのでこれで判定しておこうと思います。

他にもあると思いますが、これがとりあえずは簡単かな、と思います。

こちらの自作のライブラリでは、deno, node.js, 各ブラウザ, GoogleAppsScript などの環境判定しています。gas かどうか自体は、グローバルの Browser オブジェクトの存在判定をしています。

https://github.com/standard-software/partsjs/blob/v6.0.0/source_code/platform/platform.js

ここにRhinoかV8かの判定も近々組み込む予定です。